# PostgreSQL, get column name, column type and description

Tags: postgresql

I want to for selected table in selected schema get desired result like this

```
column_name  |  data_type   | description
-----------------------------------------
id           | integer      |  id of bill
name         | character    |
address      | character    | adress of buyer
```

**notice that some columns don't have description (column comment).**

For now i got only this query which gives me good result but only for columns which got comments (for columns that are in the selected table and don't have comment are not represented in output).

MY query which returns only data for columns that have comment is next

```
SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type, pgd.description 
from pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st 
inner join pg_catalog.pg_description pgd on (pgd.objoid=st.relid) 
inner join information_schema.columns c on (pgd.objsubid=c.ordinal_position and  c.table_schema=st.schemaname and c.table_name=st.relname)  
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'some_table';
```

How to get columns without comment in result?

Comment: just use `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` gives you an intersection of two tables. If there is no relation from a row in table A to table B, that row won't be included in the output.

Comment: tried with left join before posting question and still same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because `information_schema.columns` is the table with data for sure, and you reference it not the first, you need `right outer join` instead:

```
t=# SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type, pgd.description
from pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
inner join pg_catalog.pg_description pgd on (pgd.objoid=st.relid)
right outer join information_schema.columns c on (pgd.objsubid=c.ordinal_position and  c.table_schema=st.schemaname and c.table_name=st.relname)
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 's150';
  column_name  | data_type | description
---------------+-----------+-------------
 customer_name | text      |
 order_id      | text      |
 order_date    | date      |
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is the function [`col_description(table_oid, column_number)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

```sql
select 
    column_name, 
    data_type, 
    col_description('public.some_table'::regclass, ordinal_position)
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'some_table';
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/UGBR3Kcw)

Answer (score 2):

Use [col_description()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE) on [pg_attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html):

```
select
  attname as column_name,
  atttypid::regtype as data_type,
  col_description(attrelid, attnum) as description
from pg_attribute
where attrelid = '(myschema.)mytable'::regclass
  and attnum > 0        -- hide system columns
  and not attisdropped  -- hide dead/dropped columns
order by attnum;
```